"ce que je suis senti d'entendre"
Dans la traduction d'André Markowicz de L'adolescent de Dostoïevski, on lit :

Mais, là, soudain, entendant ce que je suis senti d'entendre sur Kraft, j'ai bondi de sur le lit, je me suis senti parcouru comme d'un soubresaut.

Je ne comprends pas la construction "entendant ce que je suis senti d'entendre sur Kraft". En russe :

Но вдруг теперь, когда я, услышав о Крафте, вскочил с кровати, меня всего обхватило как судорогой.

Il me semble qu'une traduction littérale de "услышав о Крафте" pourrait être simplement "ayant entendu parler de Kraft". Toujours est-il que même si je devine le sens, je ne comprends pas la construction grammaticale de la phrase en français.

ce que je suis censé entendre sur Kraft?

Autre traduction ici : Mais maintenant qu'en apprenant la mort de Kraft, j'avais sauté du lit, j'étais pris d'une espèce de convulsion.

Cela ressemble à un contresens du traducteur, qu'il a laissé en 1ère lecture, oublié de finaliser à la relecture et que, finalement, l'éditeur n'a pas su rectifier.
Gougueule Translate propose pour la phrase russe citée:

en français: Mais soudain, alors que, après avoir entendu parler de Kraft, j'ai sauté du lit, j'ai été saisi d'une crampe.
En anglais: But now, suddenly, when I jumped out of bed after hearing about Kraft, a spasm seized me all over.
En allemand: Doch plötzlich, als ich von Kraft gehört hatte, sprang ich aus dem Bett und überkam mich ein Krampf.
En italien: Ma all'improvviso adesso, quando, avendo sentito parlare di Kraft, sono saltato giù dal letto, sono stato colto da un crampo.

Les 4 traductions ont le même sens, que je rendrais ainsi: Mais alors que, entendant {soudain | inopinément | à l'improviste} parler de Kraft, je sautais du lit, je fus saisi d'une crampe.
Je rapproche en particulier la phrase d'A. Markowicz de la traduction italienne de GT:
"alors que, entendant ce que je suis senti d'entendre sur Kraft"  vs
"quando, avendo sentito parlare di Kraft"
ce qui me suggère que le traducteur s'orientait, à l'anglaise ou à l'allemande, vers "sentant ce qui m'était donné à entendre sur Kraft"; devinant que cela clochait, il a préféré laisser en chantier la phrase que nous lisons et a omis de la retravailler. Il l'aurait finalisée en "entendant ce qui se disait sur Kraft" ou "entendant parler de Kraft".

Merci! C'est donc bien une erreur et non une expression recherchée que je ne connaissais pas. J'aime beaucoup "entendant ce qui se disait sur Kraft" (car le narrateur ne bondit du lit qu'au moment où il entend que Kraft s'est suicidé alors qu'on parlait déjà de lui auparavant, mais il me semble qu'en russe l'auteur aurait pu formuler cette nuance et qu'elle n'existe pas ici, cependant ceci est une question pour Russian Language SE). L'explication par l'italien (entendre = sentire (it.)) est astucieuse et séduisante, mais je ne m'explique pas que A. M. soit contaminé par l'Italien.

@Bruno Ne connaissant pas le russe, je ne saurais dire s'il avait choisi"sentir" comme ersatz de entendre, percevoir ou ressentir, s'émouvoir (de). Pt^tre "Soudain, bouleversé par ce que je venais d'entendre sur Kraft, je bondis etc."?
